# Archiving by academic year instead of calendar year

Tags: posts, archives

I am building a website for a school where teachers can add posts for classwork. The posts are categorised by the class name (e.g Year 1, Year 2, etc). The academic year goes from September to July. I would like to archive previous year's posts.

Is it possible to archive (or group) posts from previous academic years and show them separately to the current year's?

I would like to do something like this:

```
/category/year-1       -> Shows Year 1 posts for current academic year.
/category/year-1/2017  -> Shows Year 1 posts for previous academic year (2017-18) .
/category/year-1/2016  -> Shows Year 1 posts for previous academic year (2016-17).
```

Is there a way that I can do this?